# How to load google map without its marker content?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, joomla2.5, google-maps-markers

On home page of my site there is google map embedded. Size of google maps is 55mb because there are 100 markers on it and every marker have image in it(in info window).
I am using following to embed it in site

```
<iframe width="1070" height="460" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=211583848080531580036.0004e201d8a2ad13f0895&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=12.993442,79.125969&amp;spn=22.947419,49.509262&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
```

I do not want to load content of all marker at once.

I have done this in one of joomla site using this code in custom html article(of Joomla)

```
{mosmap msid='211583848080531580036.0004c74a22231f20dfa00'|lat='19.997023 '|lon='73.790102'|width='900'|height='650'|zoom='12'}
```

How to use above code in site which is not on Joomla CMS.

Or

Is there other way to load google map without loading its markers content at once(on page load)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just using an iFrame with a link to google maps in your website? If so you're going about it completely the wrong way. Quite apart from using the evil iFrame (I don't like them at all, if you hadn't guessed ;) ), you have no control over the map whatsoever - the script on the website you're linking to controls the map, you're simply displaying their map to the user.

Try looking at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to see how you can have your own map on your website which you control with your script.

Of course, it's entirely possible that I've misunderstood your question. If so, please let me know and I'll try to help!